# How to loop through the alphabet via underscoreJS

Tags: javascript, list, loops, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using Underscore's template() method in BackboneJS views. I'd like to show a list of alphabet letters in my view in order to sort a collection by letter.

As a result, I have a list of 26 links (one link = one letter) in my view. Instead of copy-pasting each link (which is very bad for code maintainability), I was wondering if it was possible to loop through the alphabet via underscoreJS.

**Result to display :**

```
<li ><a href="#">a</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">b</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">c</a></li>
...
<li ><a href="#">z</a></li>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
_.each(alphabet, function(letter) {
  console.log(letter);
});
```

That's how you could do it.

Answer (score 14):

1. Create a range with the charcodes

   ```
   var alphas = _.range(
       'a'.charCodeAt(0),
       'z'.charCodeAt(0)+1
   ); 
   // [97 .. 122]
   ```
2. Create an array with the letters

   ```
   var letters = _.map(alphas, a => String.fromCharCode(a));
   // see @deefour comment

   // Non ES6 version
   // var letters = _.map(alphas, function(a) {
   //    return String.fromCharCode(a);
   // });

   // [a .. z]
   ```
3. Inject into your template

   ```
   var tpl = 
   '<ul>'+
       '<% _.each(letters, function(letter) { %>'+
           '<li><%= letter %></li>'+
       '<% }); %>'+
   '</ul>';
   var compiled = _.template(tpl);
   var html = compiled({letters : letters});
   ```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/hPdSQ/17/

```js
var alphas = _.range(
    'a'.charCodeAt(0),
    'z'.charCodeAt(0)+1
); 

var letters = _.map(alphas, a => String.fromCharCode(a));

var tpl = 
'<ul>'+
    '<% _.each(letters, function(letter) { %>'+
        '<li><%= letter %></li>'+
    '<% }); %>'+
'</ul>';
var compiled = _.template(tpl);

var html = compiled({letters : letters});

document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id='res'></div>
```

Comment: Be aware, the map over `alphas` in this answer does **not** return an array of raw characters, `"a", "b", "c", ...`. You'll instead get unicode strings like `"a\u0001\u0000", "b\u0001\u0000", "c\u0001\u0000", ...`. You should instead use an arrow function like `a => String.fromCharCode(a)` to only pass the first argument (`fromCharCode` accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, causing whatever else lodash passes to the `map` callback to be converted to null values shown above).

Answer (score 7):

```
for(var letter=65;letter<91;letter++)
{
var _char = String.fromCharCode(letter);
console.log(_char);
}
```

or use from 97 - 123 ascii code for lowercase letters

Comment: Really its simple!
declare an array and push each _char to that, ur array with alphabets ready!

Answer (score 4):

```js
for (var i = 'a'.charCodeAt(0); i <= 'z'.charCodeAt(0); i++) {
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
```

Comment: What is the use of charCodeAt(0) concatted to your starting and ending indexes?

Comment: Okay, yeah, relooking now, this does look right; it might be slightly slower than Medo Medo's, but it is slightly more readable.

Answer (score 3):

### Using ES6 [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
for(let char of "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" )
  console.log(char); // prints 'a' to 'z'
```

Pretty easy to use that in a template, and you could use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile it to code for browsers which lack support for that syntax.

Comment: You didn't answer the question directly about backbone or underscore but helped me nonetheless since I'm in ES6+. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with underscore (or loadash):

```
_.map(_.range(26), function(i) { return String.fromCharCode(97 + i) });

// returns ['a', 'b', ..., 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `underscore.js` and `jQuery` in conjunction will help you acheive this (underscore.js is incapable of doing DOM insertion/manipulation by itself).

```
var abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; //i disregarded how you get the list of letters.

_.each(abc, function(letter){
    $('ul').append('<li><a href="#">'+letter+'</a></li>');
});
```

Also made a [fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/q3vtn/)

Answer (score 0):

Underscore don't have such ability, but your case could do some trick on the template. change your template like this:

```
<% for(var i=65; i<90; i++) { %>
<li ><a href="#"><% print(String.fromCharCode(i)); %></a></li>
<% } %>
```

this should be what you want.

Comment: you missed Z , `var i = 65; i <= 90; i++` , it needed <= , but close enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an improved* version of @Medo Medo's pure JS code:

```js
    var letters=[], letter_first = 'a', letter_last = 'z' // you can also use A and Z
    for (var letter=letter_first.charCodeAt(0);letter<=letter_last.charCodeAt(0);letter++)
      letters.push(String.fromCharCode(letter))
    document.write(letters.join(''))
```

- Fixed the "var" declaration
- Added direct letter detection
- Collected the result into an array in order to have only one output
- Made the code runnable right here