# Repetition in javascript using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, repeat

I'm trying to simplify my javascript. This is what I've got:

```
$("select#selectme").change(function () {
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "select-a") {
                $('#industry').val('a1');
            }
            else if ($(this).attr("value") == "select-b") {
                $('#industry').val('b1');
            }
    });
    }).change();
```

etc, for the whole alphabet. I would like to get the letter of the alphabet dynamically, to avoid repetition: "select-x" and .val('x1); etc.
What would be the best approach? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop through the alphabet via underscoreJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788964/how-to-loop-through-the-alphabet-via-underscorejs) Doing this with jquery is an extremely minor edit.

Comment: I'm already using jQuery so seems logical to not add another library just for this solution. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: The idea wasn't to actually use _.js. But take the idea of splitting the string of all characters and iterating over it. That said, if you know for certain your values are select-X, @Ozan's solution seems ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("select#selectme").change(function () {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
        var val = $(this).attr("value"),
            letter = val.substring(val.length - 1);
        $("#industry").val(letter + "1");
    });
}).change();
```

You could get the letter like this so you dont need all the if conditions for the whole alphabet.

You are also just overriding the value of `#industry` so your iteration over the selected options seem unnecessary in this case. You could just get the value of the last one but I assume you actually have another reason for this iteration?

In case you actually do not need that loop through selected options, you can just get rid of it and get the last one

```
$("select#selectme").change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val(),
        lastval = val[val.length - 1],
        letter = lastval.substring(lastval.length - 1);
    $("#industry").val(letter + "1");
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ozan's answer is good, and I am doing similar thing. However, I am using regex, which I guess makes it more fail safe.

```
$("select#selectme").change(function () {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
        var letter = $(this).attr('value').match(/select-(.)/).n[1];
        $("#industry").val(letter+'1');
    });
}).change();
```

Comment: Thank you, both options worked fine. Why are you using this method, isn't it the same?

Comment: the other method selects the last letter from string and so on. My method checks if string exists in this form `select-x` then selects x. otherwise it doesn't

Comment: Just coming back to this topic, I have a similar situation where I need to create a glossary using the letters of the alphabet in a list, not a drop down:



    $(".alphabet .alpha-a").click(function () { $("ul.list-object-a").addClass("selected");





so alpha-a would display list-object-a, alpha-b would display list-object-b etc.


I tried using your code but I can't seem to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: it should be: `var x = $(this).attr("class").match(/alpha-(.)/)[1]; $("ul.list-object-"+x).addClass("selected");`

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, unfortunately that doesn;t work, maybe I am doing something wrong. I have one list with <a class="alpha alpha-a> etc. and one list with <ul class="list-objects list-object-a">. Clicking each link in list 1 should display the right list-object.

Comment: post new question with html in it, it will be much clearer.

Comment: Thank you, have done that. Question is called: Create a glossary alphabet in Jquery